# How to remove the nth occurence of a tag from xml using scala

Tags: xml, scala, tags

I have an xml with structure like :

```
<A>
   <B>
      <c></c>
      <c></c>
      <c></c>
   </B>
</A>
```

I want to remove just the second occurence of `<C>` from this XML and want to use the updated XML.

Can someone help me how I can do it in SCALA ?

Comment: Yes but somehow I ahven't found an example for removing nth occurence of tag in an XML. Even the link you referred to doesn't help

Comment: Have you seen `RewriteRule` and `RuleTransformer` in scala-xml?